# parent bone rotates when the chain length value is increased

Tags: rigging

I've rigged an ant and have an issue with the tail and connected shield.
When i increase the chain length to include the shield then the bone for the shield rotates...
Anyone an idea?

[example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g9eM6UGW5Jnm1S1x6VK4V5J3_1gsuoQe/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: hello could you please share the armature? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hi moonboots, I found what the issue was. It was because my control bone was moved...

Comment: oh ok, fine then  ;)